# Calcular la edad a partir de dos fechas

Tags: r

Tengo una base de datos con 55.000.000 de registros y dos variables de fechas a partir de las cuales debo calcular la edad.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito calcular la edad en el momento del chequeo NO la edad actual. Entiendo que sería una diferencia entre las dos fechas, pero no soy capaz de calcularla, utilizando diferentes scripts.

Podrían por favor indicarme como lo puedo hacer

Answer (score 0):

¡Hola @Rodelpi!

Para calcular la edad, sigue los siguientes pasos (supongamos que tus variables se llaman `fch.ini` y `fch.fin` dentro de un `data.frame` genérico llamado `df`:

1. Comprueba que tus variables tienen formato fecha

   ```
   class(df$fch.ini); class(df$fch.fin)
   ```

En caso de que no tengan formato `Date`, visto la forma de tus datos se procedería de la siguiente forma:

```
df$fch.ini <- as.Date(df$fch.ini, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
df$fch.fin <- as.Date(df$fch.fin, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
```

2. Instala el paquete `MESS` y ejecuta su función `age`

   ```
   # Cargar el paquete
     library(MESS)
   # Asignar a la nueva variable "edad" su valor correspondiente
     df$edad <- age(df$fch.ini, df$fch.fin)
   ```

El resultado proporciona la edad en años, como número entero

Comment: Buenos días, sigo teniendo problemas en el cálculo. El error que aparece ahora es > SpTH20.22$Edad <- age(SpTH20.22$ Fecha.de.chequeo.en.aeropuerto.destino, SpTH20.22$ Fecha.de.nacimiento)
Error in age(SpTH20.22$Fecha.de.chequeo.en.aeropuerto.destino, SpTH20.22$Fecha.de.nacimiento) : 
  ages cannot be negative                                                                                                   Me temo que habrá columnas con datos erróneos y no sé como solucionarlo. Son 55 millones de registros. Gracias

Comment: Eso es porque el orden de las fechas que has metido no es el correcto, primero pon la fecha de nacimiento y luego la de chequeo

Answer (score 0):

Saber la edad, dada dos fechas no es muy complejo de hacer con R base, básicamente hay que calcular la diferencia en años y luego verificar si el mes y el día de la "fecha hasta" superan los del nacimiento, para saber si hay un año menos o no. En la respuesta de Jim en [Calculate ages in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611314/calculate-ages-in-r) hay una muy óptima función, que me tomé el trabajo de mejorarla un poco:

```
age = function(from, to=Sys.Date()) {
  
  from_lt = as.POSIXlt(from)
  to_lt = as.POSIXlt(to)
  
  age = to_lt$year - from_lt$year
  idx <- to_lt$mon < from_lt$mon | 
     (to_lt$mon == from_lt$mon & to_lt$mday < from_lt$mday)
   
  age[idx] <- age[idx] - 1

  age  
}
```

Ejemplo:

```
df <- data.frame(from = '1970-06-02', 
                 to = c('1971-06-01', '1971-06-02', '2022-12-01'))

df$edad <- age(df$from, df$to)
df

        from         to edad
1 1970-06-02 1971-06-01    0
2 1970-06-02 1971-06-02    1
3 1970-06-02 2022-12-01   52
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!! Ya me ha funcionado el script